# History of the word copperas

Tags: nomenclature, history-of-chemistry

I searched for copperas on google and it says ferrous sulphate. My dictionary shows that the word copperas is derived from copper.

I was just wondering what has ferrous sulphate to do with copper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track.

The [Brockhaus Konversationslexikon (Brockhaus Encyclopedia, 14th edition, 1894-1894)](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=130317)

explains the German term *Kupferwasser* (copper water) as

> veraltete Bezeichnung für unreinen (kupferhaltigen) Eisenvitriol

which means *outdated name for impure (copper-containing) iron vitriol*.

Note that *iron vitriol* is an old term for iron(II) sulfate,  such as *vitriolic oil* is an outdated name for sulfuric acid.

If you take a look at English wikipedia page on [iron(II)sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II)_sulfate), you'll see that one of the common minerals is a heptahydrate, [melanterite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanterite). If you follow the link, you will recognize that one of the **associated minerals** is [chalcanthite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcanthite), which is $\ce{CuSO4·5H2O}$.

To cut the long story short, the term *copperas* stems from the fact that natural iron(II)sulfate was often found to be associated and maybe contaminated with copper(II)sulfate.